# 24bit depth buffer with WebGL 1.0

Tags: webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I've found that there's no `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES` renderbuffer storage equivalent in WebGL. But there's `WEBGL_depth_texture` extension that I can use to make a 24_8 or 32bit depth texture. Are those the `DEPTH_COMPONENT24`/`DEPTH_COMPONENT32` renderbuffer equivalent? It would work the same as the screen buffer?

Is this the reason why they didn't make 24/32bit depth renderbuffer for WebGL?

Answer (score 1):

<s>There's a way to allocate 24 bit depth buffer in WebGL 1: [`DEPTH_STENCIL`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#6.7). Here's a test: http://jsbin.com/tadikibidi/edit?js,output.</s> That's not actually true. The whereas the spec doesn't explicitly specifies sizes of components of `DEPTH_STENCIL` buffer, conformance tests suggest that the only requirement is for `DEPTH` to have >= 16 bit and >= 8 bit for `STENCIL`. It seems that the only way (at least w/o extensions) would be to allocate a `DEPTH_STENCIL` attachment and check `DEPTH_BITS` parameter of a framebuffer the attachment's attached to.

AFAIK, 32bit depth buffers a harder to get on mobile devices, thus WebGL doesn't have them (only with extensions).

Comment: Nowhere in the spec says it's 24bit. I've done my research. No one talks about why it isn't specified. Sure, it has to be `UNSIGNED_INT_24_8` because no hardware implements it otherwise... Or does it?

Comment: Just realised that `framebufferRenderbuffer` in WebGL 1 context indeed accepts `DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT`. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/framebufferRenderbuffer) MDN page was misleading somehow.

Comment: Yep, looks like you're right. My understanding was that it should be 24 bit, but even conformance tests aren't checking that, the only thing checked is that depth has *at least* 16 bits. I think you should post the question to public_webgl@khronos.org.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Asked the mailing list and got the answer. Can't accept your answer though, because there's no definitive way to allocate 24bit depth buffer in WebGL 1.

Answer (score 1):

What the spec doesn't also say about is that `DEPTH_STENCIL` is just an abstraction. WebGL implementations, especially the older ones, can implement `DEPTH_STENCIL` by bundling one depth buffer and one stencil buffer under the hood. So a `DEPTH_STENCIL` renderbuffer can be anything: 16/8(if 24 is not supported), 24/8(with extension) and so on. And the conformance test implies that the depth buffer is at least 16bit.

They came up with this abstraction and didn't even give a simple anatomy of what it is. Just this line pops out of nowhere:

> WebGL adds `DEPTH_STENCIL` renderbuffer

[The mailing list archive](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/public_webgl/1711/).